# Get Bytecode at runtime in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to get the Bytecode of a Module in Elixir at runtime.

I was able to save the Bytecode of a module I created using iex into a variable, but what I really want to do is get the Bytecode of an already loaded module.

I looked through the Module & Code functions but didn't find what I need yet. Could someone point me in the right direction?

This works

```
:code.get_object_code(Map)
```

But when I try to get the Bytecode for a module I wrote it says ":error"

```
defmodule Hello do
  def sayHello do
      IO.puts "hello"
  end
end

Hello.sayHello
```

# Output Showing module is loaded

```
hello
:ok
```

# Try it with a module I wrote.

```
:code.get_object_code(Hello)
```

# output

```
:error
```

Comment: interested in the answer if you found any solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions from the Erlang's `:code` module, namely `:code.get_object_code/1`.

```
iex(3)> :code.get_object_code(:elixir)
{:elixir,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 52, 64, 66, 69, ...>>,
 '/usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/ebin/elixir.beam'}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for built in Elixir Modules,  I updated my question to be more clear.  I am getting getting an error when I try it on a module I wrote in iex.

Comment: I Found out that this does work for modules I write, it only didn't work if I manually typed modules in iex.  If I manually type them in iex I can get the out put by using the v command.